# JS / jQuery : Variable .css() propertyName

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties

How can I store property name as a variable?

**Example code:**

```
var propertyName = 'margin-top';
$('elem').css({ propertyName : '10px' });
```

Comment: .css(strWhatever, value); or make a dynamic object using array syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the argument for css() as a variable, and then add the property to it:

```
var propertyName = 'margin-top';
var cssArg = {};
cssArg[propertyName] = '10px';
$('elem').css(cssArg);
```

Edit:

**In the future (ES6)** you'll be able to do that in one line using computed properies:

```
$('elem').css({ [propertyName] : '10px'});
```

But for now, you have to stick with the long way.

Answer (score 0):

For single CSS directive change, you could simply do this:

```
var propertyName = 'margin-top';
$('elem').css(propertyName, '10px');
```

If you still need to pass Object in order to manipulate multiple directives, you could try this:

```
var cssData = {};
var propertyName = 'margin-top';
cssData[propertyName] = '10px';

$('elem').css(cssData);
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)